# population model - logistic differential equation - find the critical points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

`dR/dt =(c/(1+(R^2)/(K^2))-g)R`

where k > 0 is a constant, c is the birth rate and g is the
death rate. I've assumed that the population birth rate is dependent
on the density of the population.

for two scenarios,`c>g` and `c<g`

I need to find the critical points other than R=0. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) is a MathJax tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation 
$$\dot R(t)=\left[\frac c{1+R(t)^2/K^2}-g\right]R(t)$$
has obviously $R(t)=0$ as a fixed point. For a second fixed point you need to solve 
$$\frac c{1+R(t)^2/K^2}-g=0,$$
which is equivalent to 
$$R(t)^2/K^2=c/g-1.$$
Hence, if $c/g<1$, no real solution exists. If $c/g\geq1$, you get
$$R(t)=\pm K\sqrt{c/g-1}.$$
If the interpretation of the model requires $R(t)$ to be non-negative, only one fixed point in addition to $R(t)=0$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for this, so for when $k>0$ we only have one other fixed point being +K(c/g -1)^0.5. This is the second fixed point for when c>g, when c<g would the only fixed point be 0, if so why?

Comment: Because there is no other value $R(t)$ that would make the right-hand side of your equation equal to $0$. Would you mind accepting my answer?